# How to extract key from field if the array of keys are in another table - Redshift, SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table_1 with some keys (examples: '**_ABC**', '**_ABD**', '**_DAE**' etc)

And I have table_2 with a field_1 that can contain one of the keys from table_1
example:

```
field_1              
ERUYY_ABCEWIRUEWF   
OUREWUFGHGFHG_ABD  
OWEIROEWRRUERIREE   
_DAE_SEWIREWURURR
```

How to create a field_2 in table_2, which would only contain the key from field_1 if it is in table_1 ?

As a result, I would like to get :

| field_1 | field_2 |
| --- | --- |
| ERUYY_ABCEWIRUEWF | **_ABC** |
| OUREWUFGHGFHG_ABD | **_ABD** |
| OWEIROEWRRUERIREE |  |
| _DAE_SEWIREWURURR | **_DAE** |

Thanks for help !

Comment: I believe that formula should be something like this:
'_'||left(split_part(field1,'_',2),3)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, Redshift

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `position` function to check the existence of the key in the string.
You could also use `LIKE` but it uses regular expressions that might collide with your `_` character which in REgEx terms is understood as **ANY CHARACTER**.

Let's recreate the example, with `table_1`

```
create table table_1 (field_key varchar);
insert into table_1 values('_ABC');
insert into table_1 values('_ABD');
insert into table_1 values('_DAE');
```

And `table_2`

```
create table table_2 (field_1 varchar);
insert into table_2 values('ERUYY_ABCEWIRUEWF');
insert into table_2 values('OUREWUFGHGFHG_ABD');
insert into table_2 values('OWEIROEWRRUERIREE');
insert into table_2 values('_DAE_SEWIREWURURR');
insert into table_2 values('ADAE_SEWIREWURURR');
```

If we use the `LIKE` we end up also with the match `ADAE_SEWIREWURURR` -> `_DAE` because is using regular expressions

```
select * 
from table_2 
left outer join table_1
on table_2.field_1 like '%' || table_1.field_key || '%';
```

Result

```
field_1      | field_key 
-------------------+-----------
ERUYY_ABCEWIRUEWF | _ABC
OUREWUFGHGFHG_ABD | _ABD
OWEIROEWRRUERIREE | 
_DAE_SEWIREWURURR | _DAE
ADAE_SEWIREWURURR | _DAE
(5 rows)
```

If instead we use position, we end up with the correct result (no match  `ADAE_SEWIREWURURR` -> `_DAE`)

```
select * 
from table_2 
left outer join table_1
on position(table_1.field_key in table_2.field_1) > 0;
```

Result

```
field_1      | field_key 
-------------------+-----------
ERUYY_ABCEWIRUEWF | _ABC
OUREWUFGHGFHG_ABD | _ABD
OWEIROEWRRUERIREE | 
_DAE_SEWIREWURURR | _DAE
ADAE_SEWIREWURURR | 
(5 rows)
```